Keeping the control in the command line while playing a programm like ffplay (to build an mp3 player)
I want to write an mp3 player in zsh (or bash). The first function I want to implement is to go to the next song when pressing the "n" key, however, when I launch the programm, ffplay takes over the bash script pressing "n" has no effect. How can I do that (using another program than ffplay would be fine too, the goal is the mp3 player no ffplay)
mp3_player(){
  # in th  command line, the user must be in a directory field only with mp3 files

  idx=$1 # first index given by the user
  files=(*) # make an array with all the files inside the dir
  key="" # set the value of the key to empty
  
  while :
  do
    echo ${files[$((idx))]}
    ffplay -autoexit ${files[$((idx))]}
    read -t 1 -k 1 key # for zsh
    #read -t 1 -n 1 key # for bash
  
    if [[ $key == "n" ]]
    then
      idx=$((idx+1))
      key=""
    fi
  done
}


setting aside the script for a moment ... does ffplay support this feature from the command line, ie, can you manually perform a next song operation from the console?

thank you for your comment @markp-fuso: I looked in the documentation of ffplay and did not find such operation

fwiw, running a web search on ffplay command line "next song" brings up several hits like this, this, this and this; the general idea would be to look for other tools (other than ffplay) that may have an acceptable command line interface; good luck

here's a basic but functional ffplay script,confident it works reasonably , definitely room for improvement,
NB: tested in MY environment - note the mp3dir,tunes variable need to fit use use.
#! /usr/bin/env bash

mp3dir="./mp3/"
tunes=($mp3dir/*.mp3)

displayTunes(){
    >&2 echo
    declare -i i=0
    for t in "${tunes[@]}"
    do
        >&2 echo "#${i} $(basename "$t")"
        i=$((i+1))
    done
    >&2 echo
    
    echo ${#tunes[@]}
}

mp3_player(){
    #declare -i tunePID
    currentTune=-1 # first
    isvalid='^[0-9]+|[NnSs]$'
    while :
    do
        numTunes=$(displayTunes)
        
        tune=""

        read -r -n3 -p "[${currentTune}]:enter tune # (0..$(($numTunes-1))) to play [N for next |S stop current | q to quit] :" tune
        if [[ $tune =~ $isvalid ]]
        then
            if [ "${tune,}" == "s" ]
            then
                echo 'got here'
                if [ $tunePID ]
                then
                    echo "killing $tunePID"
                    kill -9 $tunePID
                    tunePID=""
                    currentTune=-1
                fi
                
                continue
            fi
            
            if [ "${tune,}" == "n" ]
            then
                tune=$(($currentTune+1))
                echo "tune:$tune current:$currentTune"
            fi
            
            if [ $tune -le $numTunes ]
            then
                if [ $tunePID ]
                then
                    kill -9 $tunePID
                    tunePID=""
                fi
                ffplay -nodisp -nostats -autoexit "${tunes[$tune]}" > /dev/null 2>&1 &
                tunePID=$!
                currentTune=$tune
            else
                read -r -n1 -p "no more tunes, restart ?[Yy|Nn] :" restart
                [ "${restart,}" == "y" ] currentTune=-1 && continue
                [ "${restart,}" == "n" ] exit
            fi
        elif [ "${tune,}" == "q" ]
        then
            if [ $tunePID ]
            then
                kill -9 $tunePID
            fi
            echo "goodbye ${USER} and thanks for all the fish !!"
            exit;
        else
            tune=""
            continue # ignore everything else
        fi
    done
}

mp3_player

exit


feel free to use/change/ignore as you deem appropriate

many thanks for your extensive answer. I think it needs some adaptation for my machine, but this is a great source of inspiration!

Generally, if you want to run a program in the background and keep the console responsive, you'll want to start it as a job, by appending a '&' at the end of the line :
#!/bin/bash

#some script there ...

command="ffplay -autoexit ${files[$((idx))]}" #(from your first example)
job_pid="$($command &)"
kill -SIGUSR1 "${job_pid}" # assuming process at job_pid expects SIGUSR1 and wil do something with it...

Doing so will print the pid of the new process on the standard out (in my example code, this pid will be stored in the job_pid variable).
Some programs allow you simple interaction with them through process signals (like herbe for example : https://github.com/dudik/herbe)
There are also other options, like this one : https://cmus.github.io/
